# How to find the index of a subsection in an array from one string (python 3.4.2)

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, indexing

I am trying to find the index of a subsection in a multidimensional array by just inputting one of the words in that subsection. For example, if this is my array:

```
sav = [['Joseph', 'Alex', 'Josh'], ['James', 'Harvey', 'Nat']]
```

I want to find the index of the first subsection by just entering one of the names, so if I typed in 'Alex' I would get the index 0 and if I typed in 'Nat' I would get the index 1. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just can make a loop over your list and use `in` operand to check the membership :

```
>>> def find_index(name,l=sav) :
...   for i,j in enumerate(l) :
...     if name in j :
...       print ('index is : {}'.format(i))

>>> find_index('Alex')
index is : 0
>>> find_index('Nat')
index is : 1
```

Comment: I get an invalid syntax error at the apostrophe before .format(i). Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: @zeldor as your are in python 3 , you need `()` for print , i omit it first , fixed ! ;)

Comment: When I try this, it doesn't print anything, even though the string is definitely in the array

Comment: @zeldor whats the problem ?

Comment: Oh sorry there wasn't a problem I just mis-clicked.